# Passing data between fragments through ViewModel

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

let say for example I have 1 `Activity` that contains 5 `Fragments` and those `Fragments` presents a 1 flow of payment process so each `Fragment` depends on the previous `Fragment` by passing data of what the user chooses
I'm planning to make 1 `ViewModel` in the `Activity` that handles the data between `fragments` but I've read that it is a bad idea to expose `MutableLiveData` outside of the view model. so I can't say `viewModel.setdata(example)` in the `Activity` the best solution was is to use `navigation component` with safe args and create a `ViewModel` for each `Fragment` and create `ViewModelFactory` for each fragment too. 
but this will make me write too many classes.

is there an optimal way to pass data between views using 1 ViewModel without violating the MVVM architecture rules?

Comment: If those 5 fragments are doing lots of different things, then go for different viewmodels for each fragment (if you don't, then you'll end up with a god viewmodel). Otherwise, create a single viewmodel with the activity scope. `viewModel.onNextClicked(data)` is a perfectly valid thing. Just pass your data to the viewmodel and update the livedata from the viewmodel internally and observe that livedata in all your fragments. Again, only do this if the fragments have some shared logic/behavior/data.

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is good decision to use ViewModel to share data between fragments. Look [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

Answer (score 0):

SharedViewModel

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

public void select(Item item) {
    selected.setValue(item);
}

public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
    return selected;
}
}
```

MasterFragment

```
public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
private SharedViewModel model;

public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
        model.select(item);
    });
}
}
```

DetailFragment

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    SharedViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    model.getSelected().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), item -> {
       // Update the UI.
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the black magic:

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
```