# Android: Pass data between fragments using bundle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

I'm trying to pass data between fragments of different activities using bundles.

I have two fragments:
Fragment A is attached on Activity A;
Fragment B is attached on another activity: Activity B.

I need to pass an edit text string from Fragment A to Fragment B.
How can i accomplish that using bundles?
Can someone give me an example in kotlin?

This is what I've tried so far:

Fragment A:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
                    bundle.putString("data", emailField)
                    val dashboardFragment = DashboardHomeFragment()
                    dashboardFragment.arguments = bundle
                    parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                        replace(R.id.home_nav_graph, dashboardFragment)
                        commit()
                    }
```

Fragment B:

```
val inputData = arguments?.getString("data")
binding.emailCv.text = inputData.toString()
```

Comment: If the fragments are part of 2 diff activities then you need to pass the said data to next activity in your case activity B then the same can be passed to the target fragment B when Activity B initiates this new fragment.

Comment: Fragments are supposedly reusable.  Maybe you can host both on the same activity?

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass data from Fragment A to activity B. Then Activity B can send the data to Fragment B

For Example:

**In Fragment A**

```
val intent = Intent(context, ActivityB::class.java)
intent.putExtra("data", emailField)
startActivity(intent)
```

**In Activity B**

```
val myData = intent.getStringExtra("data")
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("data", myData) 
val fragmentB = FragmentB()
fragmentB.arguments = bundle
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                     replace(R.id.home_nav_graph, fragmentB)
                     commit()}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked.
So basically there's no way to pass data between fragments (directly) if they live in different activities

Comment: @JonathanQuaranta No, you cannot 'directly' share data between 2 fragments with different host activities. Its actually data sharing between 2 activities then the 2nd host activity shares the data with the attached fragment.